# How to get relative URL of medium sized featured image?

Tags: images, featured-post

How to show featured image (medium sized) relative URL (relative to the website root)?

I need something like this: `uploads/214/07/image-600x400.png`

I tried with this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $medium_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
    echo $medium_image_url[0];  
}
```

It works fine, I get path of medium sized featured image, but with domain name too, and I need it without domain name.

Also I tried like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$the_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$the_thumbnail_name = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = '$the_thumbnail_id' AND meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'" );
//
echo $the_thumbnail_name;
```

This works fine, I get just relative path, but "full" sized featured image path, and I need "medium" sized featured image path.

Can anyone help me, maybe redesign (adding some parameter for "medium" size) of second function, or some new approach?

Comment: Would be good to know the reason you want to do this..

Comment: I need it to use in function to get medium sized featured image file size. Example, in function `echo getSize('medim-size-url-here.jpg');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with your first snippet - from there it's easy to remove parts of the url: check what WP has stored as the site root, then use php's string functions to snip that part out of your image url.

```
// inside the post loop, in a template file
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
  $medium_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
  $domain = get_site_url(); // returns something like http://domain.com
  $relative_url = str_replace( $domain, '', $medium_image_url[0] );
  echo $relative_url;
}
```

If you wanted this to exist as a reusable function:

```
// functions.php
function get_relative_thumb( $size ) {
   global $post;
   if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
     $absolute_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);
    $domain = get_site_url(); // returns something like http://domain.com
    $relative_url = str_replace( $domain, '', $absolute_url[0] );
    return $relative_url;
   }
}

// in a template file
<?php 
      while (have_posts) : the_post();

      // ... post loop content before the thumbnail

      echo get_relative_thumb( 'medium' ); 

      // ... post loop content after the thumbnail

      endwhile;
?>
```

(Note - the result from this will likely still include the 'wp-content/' part of the path; if you need to remove that so it just starts at 'upload', just append 'wp-content' to the $domain variable before you run str_replace. (If this is intended for general release, you should use wordpress' built-in functions to get the path programatically, in case someone isn't using the typical 'wp-content' directory structure.)

Comment: Great solution @jack.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I just need little more help. I tried first your snippet and I get "/my-upload-folder/image-name.jpg", but I need "my-upload-folder/image-name.jpg". So, just without first"/". Any help?

Comment: Also I tried second snippet (as a reusable function), and it break my page, I get blank page. But, anyway, first snippet is working, and I do not need it often.

Comment: My bad - I just realized I missed a bracket in the second snippet. Edited; it should work now. As to your first question, you can include that forward slash in your string replacement: `relative url = str_replace( $domain . '/', '', $medium_image_url[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

No need to str_replace(), just pass the full absolute URL to [wp_make_link_relative](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_make_link_relative/)().

The built-in function is much simpler and also neatly handles trailing slashes, situations where home_url and site_url are different and various other edge cases.